# How to display more than 3 view in wearable list row

Tags: wear-os

I have wearablelistitem with more than 3 textview in vertical manner,but the last text view cut from bottom.Is there any way to add more than 3 and 4 views in single list item.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using the WearableListView.